# Unable to upload reports to TFS 2018 Project Collection

Tags: team-foundation-server, ssrs

I'm trying to add reports to my TFS 2018 installation following the tutorial [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/admin/add-reports-to-a-team-project?toc=/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/toc.json&bc=/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=tfs-2018). When I get to the 'Upload reports to a team project' step, I execute the command

```
TFSConfig addprojectreports /collection:"http://myServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" /teamproject:MyProject /template:"TemplateName"
```

and get the error "Access Denied: User needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Delete this catalog node and its children" The User in this case is a Server admin, TFS admin and SQL Server admin. Not sure what permissions I'm missing. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So this was silly but I'll post the answer on the off chance that someone else does this. My user belonged to a group that explicitly denied permissions to modify the team project I was trying to upload the reports to. So even though I had admin access, the Deny trumped everything else. Removing myself from the group fixed it.